# Which is correct: "prefer X to Y" or "prefer X over Y"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, formality

Many say that "prefer X to Y" has a more formal ring to it than "prefer X over Y". Are there any dialects where you wouldn't use "prefer X to Y" in colloquial speech at all? Conversely, are there any manuals of style that discourage using "prefer X over Y" in formal writing?

Comment: "Prefer over" sounds alien to me as a British English speaker, so I assume it must be an American English convention.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [Merriam-Webster Dictionary of English Usage (MDEU) suggests](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA760#v=onepage&q=prefer&f=false) that *to* is the ordinary word used to construct comparisons using *prefer*: “when it is used to compare two things in the same sentence, the second […] is usually introduced by *to*.” They note that *over* (“Nine out of ten dentists prefer *Crest* over the competitors”), and *rather than* (“He prefers to stand rather than to sit”) are also used. *Rather than* is especially helpful when the compared items are infinitive clauses beginning with *to*, therefore avoiding the problem of too many *to*s ( * “He prefers to stand to to sit”). *Above* can also be used (“Prefers this brand above all others”), although they note that *above*, along with *before*, were noted by the OED as being used formerly.

MDEU notes that some commenters have criticized constructions with *than* and *rather than*, and suggests ultimately that plain *than* (“He would have preferred to fast than carry it”) is awkward because it is unfamiliar.

With respect to colloquial speech, I think that in some informal registers you wouldn’t use the verb *prefer* at all (which is a formal word), and would use *like* and a compatible syntactic comparative construction: “I like sleeping more than working”

Answer (score 17):

There may be a transatlantic divide here. As a speaker of BrEng I would always say *I would  prefer tea to coffee*, and never *I would prefer tea over coffee*.

Comment: I think you're right about the transatlantic divide; checking Google Ngrams, "prefer this to" [is preferred  overwhelmingly to](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prefer+this+to%2Cprefer+this+over&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) "prefer this over" in American English, but "over" isn't even common enough to get on the chart in British English.

Comment: `Ì prefer this over that` could be a literal translation from Dutch `Ik verkies dit boven dat`.

Comment: FWIW, as an American English speaker, I would also never say "prefer over." I think it is both redundant and a corruption of the actual idiom.

Answer (score 11):

> A: Would you like a ride?
>
> B: No thanks, I prefer to walk.

You can't use *prefer over* in this case. *Over* is used when there are two clear choices in the phrase.

Think of *over* as setting a list of preferences and putting one over top the other.

> I prefer jogging over running and walking.
>
> I prefer fish over beef and chicken.

In these two examples, the meaning could be slightly ambiguous and sound like you're comparing two things, not three.

> I prefer jogging to running and walking.
>
> I prefer fish to beef and chicken.

Comment: "No thanks, I prefer to walk"; The "to" in your example is part of the infinitive that you are using ("to walk"). Compare "I prefer a walk" or "Would you like (a) coffee?" "No thanks, I prefer tea".

Answer (score 4):

My brain does not differentiate the two:

"I prefer sleeping to working"

"I prefer sleeping over working"

Sounds the same to me- perhaps "prefer/to" flows slightly better. On the other hand "prefer/to" is more likely to be ambiguous:

"I prefer sleep to work"

In conversation the word "rather" seems more common than "prefer" but others may have different experience. Either way- I would be shocked if anyone criticized your usage of "prefer/to" versus "prefer/over" in any unambiguous context- formal or not.

Comment: How is "I prefer sleep to work." ambiguous?

Comment: Someone complaining that their sleep wasn't restful enough. :)
ie. Their sleep isn't working.

Comment: Sorry no that is not ambigious, rather that is poor use of English. No one would ever say their sleep isn't working.

Comment: How do you like the new carpool to work program? I don't like it, I prefer sleep to work.

Answer (score 4):

They are both grammatically correct.

"Tea over Coffee" sounds the slightest bit metaphorical to me, and so might have some rhetorical implications in a longer narrative, but that's about the only real difference.

Answer (score 4):

When we say *prefer* there is an implied *over*.

Thus, *prefer over* is tautological. I think *prefer to* is preferable.