# "Prefer tea to/over coffee"

Tags: comparatives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Which is correct: “prefer X to Y” or “prefer X over Y”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/which-is-correct-prefer-x-to-y-or-prefer-x-over-y)

Which is correct?

> I prefer tea **to** coffee.
>
> I prefer tea **over** coffee.