# sentence with "I prefer something to something"

Tags: word-usage

I know for sure that the following 3 sentences are grammatically correct since I took them from the grammar book:
I prefer jumping to running.
I prefer jumping rather than running.
I prefer to jump rather than run.

Based on this I think it is correct to say as well:  I prefer to jump rather than running.

My question is this 4th sentence correct?

Comment: *Why* do you think it is correct to mix the tenses, contrary to the examples?

Comment: Well. Those first 3 sentences come from the grammar book so this is a question to the author.   what about the 4th one. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not preserve parallelism, which violates the Gricean maxim of manner (be as clear and as straightforward as possible) even if it is not actually ungrammatical.

From [Evergreen.edu](https://www.evergreen.edu/sites/default/files/writingcenter/handouts/grammar/parallel.pdf):

> **Parallel structure** adds both clout and clarity to your writing. When you use parallel structure, you increase the readability of your
> writing by creating word patterns readers can follow easily.
>
> **Understanding Parallel Structure** Parallel structure (also called parallelism) is the repetition of a chosen grammatical form within a
> sentence. By making each compared item or idea in your sentence follow
> the same grammatical pattern, you create a parallel construction.
>
> Example
>
> - Not Parallel:
>   *Ellen likes hiking, the rodeo, and to take afternoon naps.*
> - Parallel: *Ellen likes hiking, attending the rodeo, and taking afternoon naps.*
>
> OR
>
> - *Ellen likes to hike, attend the rodeo, and take afternoon naps.*
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks Edwin. I think I've caugth it. PS. I can say: I prefer cars to bikes. But can I say: I prefer cars rather than bikes?

Comment: nohat gives sound advice  [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/which-is-correct-prefer-x-to-y-or-prefer-x-over-y)